# Selenium how to clear cache using chromedriver and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I found Java examples that explain that clearing the cache is as simple as this:

Sample Code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);

        ChromeOptions opts = new ChromeOptions();
        opts.addArguments("start-maximized");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opts);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
```

I attempted to do the same in C# 4.6 and Selenium WebDriver 2.45, but DesiredCapabilities does not contain an enum or string for ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION. I do not understand why the C# version would not have the same options available as the java version. My hunch is that there is a trick, such as directly using a string that represents the same capability that is available in java as an enum, I'm just not sure what it is.

Here is my code:

// The SetCapability(..) method call is meaningless...

```
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
                capabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, true); // ? can't set ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, intellisense shows it does not exist

                var options = new ChromeOptions();

                options.AddArguments("test-type");                  

                return new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply force chrome to start in incognito mode

```
capabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switcher", new [] {"--incognito"});
```

Comment: That usage has been deprecated. I am doing the same exact thing by doing this: var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("incognito");

Comment: I am hoping to not use incognito mode.

Comment: @sapbucket yeah, sorry. I haven't used webdriver for a while. Actually, if I remember correctly ChromeDriver creates a new temp profile for each session. If it is, I don't see any reason clearing cache.

Comment: @sapbucket [By default, ChromeDriver will create a new temporary profile for each session.](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Comment: I'm using a saved profile (not temporary) due to a plethora of developer settings I'm working with. If I didn't have this requirement I would be using incognito or just launching it, in a heartbeat

Comment: @sapbucket what if you try `var di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"Google\Chrome\User Data", "your_profile_name", "Cache"));
            di.Delete(true);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void clearCache(this ChromeDriver driver)
    {
        string cmd = @"@ECHO OFF & CD %temp% & FOR /d %D IN (*) DO RD /s /q ""%D"" & DEL /F /Q *";

        ExecuteCommand(cmd);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
        ShadowRoot shadowRoot1 = driver.getShadowRootElement(By.CssSelector("settings-ui"));
        ShadowRoot shadowRoot2 = driver.getShadowRootElement(shadowRoot1.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-main")));
        ShadowRoot shadowRoot3 = driver.getShadowRootElement(shadowRoot2.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-basic-page")));
        ShadowRoot shadowRoot4 = driver.getShadowRootElement(shadowRoot3.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-section > settings-privacy-page")));
        ShadowRoot shadowRoot5 = driver.getShadowRootElement(shadowRoot4.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog")));
        IWebElement root6 = shadowRoot5.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataDialog"));

        IWebElement root2 = root6.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iron-pages#tabs")).FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-dropdown-menu#clearFromBasic"));
        ShadowRoot shadowRoot7 = driver.getShadowRootElement(root2);
        IWebElement ddnTimeRange = shadowRoot7.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select#dropdownMenu"));
        new SelectElement(ddnTimeRange).SelectByValue("4");

        IWebElement clearDataButton = root6.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm"));
        clearDataButton.Click(); // click that hard to reach button!
    }

    public static IJavaScriptExecutor Scripts(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        return (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    }

    private static void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;

        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
    }

    private static ShadowRoot getShadowRootElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(by);
        return (ShadowRoot)driver.Scripts().ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    }

    private static ShadowRoot getShadowRootElement(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        return (ShadowRoot)driver.Scripts().ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?